# What is $\vec{v}(\vec{\gamma}(t))$?

Tags: derivatives, vector-fields, parametrization

If we got the curve $\vec{\gamma}:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R^3}$

$$\vec{\gamma}(t) = \left(\!
\begin{array}{c}
t \\
t^2+1 \\
t
\end{array}
\!\right) $$

And the vector field $\vec{v}:\mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^3}$

$$\vec{v}(x,y,z) = \left(\!
\begin{array}{c}
f'(x) \\
g'(y) \\
h'(z)
\end{array}
\!\right) $$

Where $f,g,h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are continuous and differentiable.

What would $\vec{v}(\vec{\gamma}(t))$ become?

Comment: What are $f,g,h$?

Comment: I don't know that, they are not defined.

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say "what would $\vec{v}(\vec{\gamma}(t))$ become?" Are you asking for a formula, or its properties?

Comment: Sorry, yeah I wonder how this composite formula would look like.

Comment: You can just substitute it in. Where are you having troubles?

Comment: Just substitute: $\vec v(\vec \gamma(t)) = (f'(t), g'(t^2+1),h'(t))$.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say
$$\vec{v}(t) = \left(\!
\begin{array}{c}
f'(t) \\
g'(t^2+1) \\
h'(t)
\end{array}
\!\right) $$
The composition gives you a vector depending only on the $t$ variabile.